# Re-use of clustering algorithm in python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

I have built a clustering model that is working quite well to segment data.  I've used a two step process (KMeans then Hierarchical) to avoid the memory issues that occurred when I tried Hierarchical directly (see reference https://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/data-science/data-science-performing-hierarchical-clustering-with-python/).

My question relates to how to utilize this process now to score new information.  I'm trying to keep my code structured, and i would want to "export" and "import" the relevent code, but I don't know how to export the two models.  Here is my code:

```
data_scaled = normalize(col_final_df)
data_scaled = pd.DataFrame(data_scaled, columns=col_final_df.columns)

clustering = KMeans(n_clusters=km_seg, n_init=10,
                    random_state=1)
clustering.fit(data_scaled)

post_clust_centres = clustering.cluster_centers_
post_clust_data_mapping = {case: cluster for case, cluster in enumerate(clustering.labels_)}

print('KMeans analysis complete.  Composing hierarchical segmentation of KMeans presently...')

Hclustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=29, affinity="cosine", linkage ="complete")
Hclustering.fit(post_clust_centres)

print('Hierarchical segmentation complete.  Composing dendrogram...')

plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
plot_dendrogram(Hclustering, labels=Hclustering.labels_)
plt.show()

H_mapping = {case: cluster for case,
                               cluster in enumerate(Hclustering.labels_)}
final_mapping = {case: H_mapping[post_clust_data_mapping[case]]
                 for case in post_clust_data_mapping}
```

Comment: Ok..so I've found fit_predict() will apply this score to a new sample.  But how do i export the weights so that I can use in a different function without having to re-fit my original data for this purpose.

Comment: As I understand, you need to save the model/weights. Have you tried saving the model(s) to pickles? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-python-pickling-example/

Comment: I didn't think that I needed to use pickling, but it turns out this was an elegant solution.  thank you!  Will paste my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So pickling made it easy as I could save the entire object and re-import it upon demand in the new function.  Realizing it will utilize too much i/o, i will ensure i do this only once.

To pickle, i added the following code at the end of my cluster algorithm.

```
    with open(Config.PATH + '/kmeans.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(clustering, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    with open(Config.PATH + '/hclust.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(Hclustering, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

And then this is the scoring code I used to derive segments for data vectors:

```
def score_data(data):
    with open(Config.PATH + "/kmeans.pickle", 'rb') as handle:
        clustering = pickle.load(handle)

    with open(Config.PATH + "/hclust.pickle", 'rb') as handle:
        Hclustering = pickle.load(handle)

    data_scaled = normalize(data)
    data_scaled = pd.DataFrame(data_scaled, columns=data.columns)

    clustering.labels_ = clustering.predict(data_scaled)
    post_clust_data_mapping = {case: cluster for case, cluster in enumerate(clustering.labels_)}

    H_mapping = {case: cluster for case,
                                   cluster in enumerate(Hclustering.labels_)}
    final_mapping = {case: H_mapping[post_clust_data_mapping[case]]
                     for case in post_clust_data_mapping}

    final_mapping_ls = list(final_mapping.values())

    return [x + 1 for x in final_mapping_ls]
```